# UPDATE e SELECT ao mesmo tempo (locked)

Tags: mysql, otimização

Monitorando o banco de dados (MySQL) através do [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) percebo que, quando alguma query muito grande é executada (SELECT) e, ao mesmo tempo, uma query de update também roda, sob a mesma tabela, o update fica aguardando o SELECT terminar.

O resultado disto é que a tabela fica travada aguardando (locked). E, com isto, todas as outras query's sob esta tabela (executadas no momento) não rodam enquanto não terminar, gerando assim, um grande travamento do sistema.

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Depois de realizar uma pesquisa, entendi que isto é um comportamento padrão do engine MyISAM. Ou seja, devo procurar otimizar ainda mais minhas query's para que não tenham um tempo elevado. Correto?

Comment: MyISAM é uma engine que está em desuso, recomendo mudar a engine para InnoDB. Se isso não for possível, coloque `EXPLAIN` antes do seu `SELECT` para ver o que está impactando no depempenho da query :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` para ativar o recurso de `NOLOCK`.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
-- sua query...
COMMIT;
```

Para fazer esse recurso valer para todas as queries, coloque a seguinte linha na sua configuração do MySQL:

```
[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED
```

Comment: Certo Rodrigo. Qual será o impacto desta mudança em um sistema de médio-grande porte?

Minha preocupação é a seguinte: Um UPDATE será realizado na tabela. O SELECT efetuada é um cálculo sob esta tabela. E ai, como fica?

Comment: Só sei desse recurso na teoria, nunca tive de usá-lo. Entretanto, para um sistema de grande porte, eu consideraria dividir as máquinas do MySQL em máquinas do tipo slave e master, afim de distribuir o load entre elas.

Comment: Entendi, Rodrigo. Adicionei um comentário à minha resposta. Obrigado!